# Oracle XE and DBeaver: ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, dbeaver, oracle-xe

I need to connect  to Oracle XE 18.0.0 through DBeaver 7.0 but failed due to error *Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor*
The connection to Oracle with SQLPlus works without any issue.
I`ll really appreciate any idea that will help to solve this problem.

tnsnames.ora

```
XE =
      (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.Y.YY)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SERVER = DEDICATED)
          (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
        )
      )
    
    LISTENER_XE =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.Y.YY)(PORT = 1521))
    
    
    ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
      (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SID = CLRExtProc)
          (PRESENTATION = RO)
        )
      )
```

listener.ora

```
DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\YYY\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\YYY\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.Y.YY)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

lsnrctl status

```
 LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 20-JUN-2020 17:03:44

Copyright (c) 1991, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.Y.2YY)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                20-JUN-2020 16:09:45
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 54 min. 3 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\YYY\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\app\YYY\product\18.0.0\diag\tnslsnr\YYYPC\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.Y.YY)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

global_name

```
SQL> select * from global_name;

GLOBAL_NAME
--------------------------------
XE
```

service_name

```
SQL> select value from v$parameter where name='service_names';

VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------------
XE
```

Comment: what is the output of `select value from v$parameter where name='local_listener'` ?

Comment: @pifor , it's

`LISTENER_XE`

Comment: It should work unless you changed IP address of the machine. What is the output of `tnsping listener_XE` in `cmd.exe` ?

Comment: @pifor

`C:\Users\YYY>tnsping listener_XE

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 20-JUN-2020 17:41:39

Copyright (c) 1997, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\app\YYY\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.Y.YY)(PORT = 1521))
OK (0 msec)`

Comment: Are you masking real IP address of the machine ? This is not really needed as an IP starting with `192.168` can only be a LAN address (mine is 192.168.1.10 but you cannot do anything with that -:) ). Double check that you always have the same IP address in `tnsnames.ora` and `listener.ora`.

Comment: `tnsping listener_XE` is OK. What is the connect string that use with SQLPlus ? Do you have any error in `C:\app\YYY\product\18.0.0\diag\tnslsnr\YYYPC\listener\trace\listener.log` ? Try to use same connect string in DBWeaver as SQLPLUS.

Comment: OK, I got it :-) TCP, LAN and so on is not my strong point...
_"Double check that you always have the same IP address in tnsnames.ora and listener.ora"_
I shoud say I didn't only double check it, I triple checked it and N-times check it :-(
It's absolutely the same.
I use `sqlplus/ as sysdba` to connect to SQLPlus

Comment: And does connection work or not ?

Comment: @pifor,
listener.log
`Trace level is currently 0

2020-06-20T17:30:54.547482+03:00
Started with pid=8100
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.0.20)(PORT=1521)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
2020-06-20T17:30:58.937489+03:00
Listener completed notification to CRS on start

TIMESTAMP * CONNECT DATA [* PROTOCOL INFO] * EVENT [* SID] * RETURN CODE
20-JUN-2020 17:30:59 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=Stitch))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=LISTENER)(VERSION=301989888)) * status * 0
`

Comment: @pifor
and the rest part of log

`2020-06-20T17:31:17.446566+03:00
20-JUN-2020 17:31:17 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=DBeaver 7.0.3 - Main)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=Stitch))(SERVICE_NAME=XE)) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.0.20)(PORT=53576)) * establish * XE * 12514
TNS-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
2020-06-20T17:41:39.911587+03:00
20-JUN-2020 17:41:39 * ping * 0`

Comment: @pifor,
`sqlplus/ as sysdba` works perfectly.
Also I tried to connect as SYSTEM. It also works

`C:\Users\Stitch>sqlplus
SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sat Jun 20 18:09:40 2020
Version 18.4.0.0.0

SQL> SELECT * FROM battles;

NAME                 date
-------------------- ---------
#Cuba62b             25-OCT-62
Guadalcanal          15-NOV-42

`

Comment: That's because with sqlplus you connect without network and issue is that Oracle listener does not "see" your XE instance but with `local_listener` and correct IP address in `tnsnames.ora`: listener should see it. Try to run `alter system register;` with SQLPLUS.

Comment: OK, I run it.
`SQL> alter system register;

System altered.`

Should I restart listener?

Comment: No: just wait 1 minute and check output of `lsnrctl status`.

Comment: `Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.20)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                20-JUN-2020 17:30:54
Uptime                    0 days 1 hr. 4 min. 47 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
`

Comment: The rest one  
`Listener Parameter File   C:\app\Stitch\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\app\Stitch\product\18.0.0\diag\tnslsnr\StitchPC\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.0.20)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully`

Comment: Unfortunately it means it does not work : we should have something similar to https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xeinw/connecting-oracle-database-xe.html. Maybe something has changed on your computer about network setup and this could be the reason. **You should make sure that the IP address used by Oracle does *not* change**: could be that using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` is a better choice (for this you would need to change `listener.ora`, `tsnames.ora`, restart listener and restart database instance).

Comment: Possible causes: you have switched from  Wifi connection to LAN connection (or vice-versa) and Windows IP address has changed or you have Windows firewall blocking some IP addresses. To go further you need to check Windows network configuration for `192.68.0.20`: is IP address valid?  can it be reached with TCP IP port 1521 ?

Comment: @pifor, I run `netstat -a` and it said `TCP    192.168.0.20:1521      StitchPC:0             LISTENING` ,if I got right what your meant...
I checked firewall, it doesn't block this IP

Comment: Yes that looks good but not sure this is enough to check that there is no firewall blocking something. I can suggest trying `nmap`. but I cannot really help more for network troubleshooting on Windows.

Comment: @pifor, I just turned off all firewalls - nothing has changed...  Anyway thank you so much for your help. It's really priceless

Comment: Good luck with Oracle XE !

Answer (score 1):

My issue was having selected "Service name" instead of "SID", switching to SID solved the issue. (I was specifying a database name in the connection)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by connecting with system instead of sys. So

```
conn system/[password]@localhost:1521 as sysdba;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know at a very high level but if you are working with your local database, you can try restarting your computer. It will resolve the issue.

These references might be useful.

1. [t_ora_12514_tns_listener_does_not_currently_know_service_requested](http://dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12514_tns_listener_does_not_currently_know_service_requested.htm)
2. [forums.toadworld.com/t/ora-12514-tns-listener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-descriptor](https://forums.toadworld.com/t/ora-12514-tns-listener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-descriptor/56185)
3. [dbeaver.io/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=658](https://dbeaver.io/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=658)

Answer (score 0):

For me selecting SID instead of Service Name, and in Database I wrote xe, and it worked.